# How to submit multiple forms to same flask page?

Tags: python, html, forms, post, flask

I have multiple forms in a page.On submit it all should goto same page for processing.
But how will I address that?

Currently I have this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        project = request.form['project_name']
```

But this doesn't specify from which form I am submitting data from. Is there anyway to specify form to be processed?

Comment: Just have a hidden field with the form identification

Comment: means? i didnt understand

Comment: Add `<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="I am form 1 of project <?= $projectName; ?>" />` and test it in your PHP

Comment: I am not using php...its python flask

Comment: Whatever. On the server

Comment: He is saying add a new field to your form. The populate it using Jinja2 templating utility. E.g. render the template and pass the variable for your project data, then you could say, like the example input field above, but replace the PHP gumph with {{ project.id }}